# Why can't I apply ToUpper() to an OwnerNode?

Tags: string, powershell, methods, invocation

This works:

```
Output "Cluster Group: ""$($Group.Name)"", Current Owner: $($Group.OwnerNode), Current State: $($Group.State)"
```

This does not work:

```
Output "Cluster Group: ""$($Group.Name)"", Current Owner: $($Group.OwnerNode.ToUpper()), Current State: $($Group.State)"
```

With an error of this:

```
Method invocation failed because [Microsoft.FailoverClusters.PowerShell.ClusterNode] doesn't contain a method named 'ToUpper'.
```

Any ideas on how to get this to string from the output of the Get-ClusterGroup string to upper case?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

ToUpper() is a string method and OwnerNode is probably not a string. Call the ToString() method before calling ToUpper().

```
$($Group.OwnerNode.ToString().ToUpper())
```

Answer (score 7):

As [Shay Levy](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16963722/1630171) already explained, `OwnerNode` is not a string and has thus not a method `ToUpper()`. You can call `ToUpper()` on its `Name` property, though:

```
$($Group.OwnerNode.Name.ToUpper())
```